# What resources (books, videos, etc) to help develop math thinking skills?

Tags: reference-request, mathematical-modeling

I am a applied mathematics major and have taken basic undergraduate coursework up to multi-variable calculus, ordinary differential equations, and elementary linear algebra.  I am currently taking mathematical modeling and boundary value problems courses.  I didn't struggle as much before with previous work but much of what I am doing now involves constructing and conceptualizing problems using assumptions and coming up with solutions without using a specific method.  What is out there to help develop a better mathematical intuition and give approaches to solving modeling type problems?